# workalendar.europe library: how to find holidays

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the holiday name passing the date in workalendar.europe library but I have no results

```
form workalendar.europe import France
cal._holidays.get(datetime.date(2015, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `workalendar.core.Calendar.holidays` which returns a list of `(date, holiday)` pairs:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from workalendar.europe import France
>>> cal = France()
>>> d = datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)
>>> holiday_map = dict(cal.holidays(d.year))  # list -> dict
>>> holiday_map.get(d, '?')
'New year'
```